# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/spinsci/empportal/ContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I'm trying to deploy a war file to my local server through Tomcat manager webapp.When I'm trying to start post deployment.I'm getting error as application at context path could not be started.
here is web.xml and context.xml.

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/EmpPortal1"></Context>
```

Web.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <web-app>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.spinsci.empportal.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>OnAppLoad</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emp.servlets.OnAppLoad</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Authentication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emp.servlets.Authentication</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>OnLeave</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emp.servlets.LeaveInformationServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Empdir</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emp.servlets.Empdir</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApproveRejectServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.emp.servlets.ApproveRejectServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OnAppLoad</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OnAppLoad</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Empdir</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/empdir</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Authentication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/auth</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OnLeave</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OnLeave</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApproveRejectServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ApproveRejectServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

What might be reason behind Fail dialogue.Please let me know.

Added Server Logs

```
Apr 22, 2016 1:09:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Apr 22, 2016 1:09:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.spinsci.empportal.ContextListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/spinsci/empportal/ContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.spinsci.empportal.Contex$
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3111)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1348)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1828)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1717)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1516)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The reason is printed in server log.

Comment: The `path` attribute shouldn't be present in a `META-INF/context.xml` file.

Comment: Can you post the error(s) reported in the server log file?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I tried removing entire ' path="/EmpPortal1". ' Not working though.

Answer (score -1):

Context Path (or) Context Root must be unique for each application deployed on the server.

So you can't deploy two applications with same context root to the same server. It seems for both of your applications the context path is /.

Check server.xml to see what context path both of them have. If they are not unique, then change them to solve the problem.

But if you want the same context root for both applications, then you need to deploy them in two different servers.